# how to create multi images input and single output tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am trying to create a dataset something like where my `model.evaluate` func will be like this:-

```
model.evaluate([img1, img2, img3, img4], labels)
```

but since there was a really large amount of data I decided to use `tf.dataset`, but how can I create a dataset like this?

I know how to create a simple image dataset like this:-

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

I am little new to TensorFlow and deep learning, so I don't know how to do something like this, I tried to see all the available guides, but that didn't help unfortunately, I was not able to understand them.

Comment: So are you trying to use a model that has 4 independent image data sets? Not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @GerryP Yes, I am using independent data sets but output will be one, what I am actually doing is giving spectrogram of audio and images of people and trying to classify whom does audio belong to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for this, I ended up using tf.io.TFRecordWriter and tf.train.Example, so, if anyone looking for a solution for this, could look at these.